# Add rewrite rule to permalink structure

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a Custom Structure setup for posts in Settings > Permalinks as:

`/%category%/%post_id%-%postname%`

This works great for most of my posts, but there is one category that I want to remove the post_id from so it looks like this:

`/%category%/%postname%`

So if the category is MOUSE and the post-id is 123 and postname(slug) is my-great-mouse-post, then the permalink correctly looks like this:

`mydomain.com/mouse/123-my-great-mouse-post`

But if the category is DOG then I do not want the post-id, so it should look like this:

`mydomain.com/dog/my-great-dog-post`

I understand how to use actions and filters in my functions.php and in a plugin and I think I want to use add_rewrite_rule but am honestly confused as how to write the rule as regex is complicated and I do not understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Add a new rewrite rule:

```
add_action('init', function()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^dog/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?cat=dog&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}, 10, 0);
```

#### 2. Filter the post link:

```
add_filter('post_link', function($post_link, $post, $leave_name = false, $sample = false)
{
    if ( is_object_in_term($post->ID, 'category', 'DOG') ) {
        $post_link = str_replace($post->ID . '-', '', $post_link);
    }

    return $post_link;

}, 10, 4);
```

Try it in your `functions.php`. Hope it works for you!

Comment: You are a genius. I spent hours and hours trying to figure this out. Works great. I added `flush_rewrite_rules();` in the add_rewrite_rules function as I am using this in a plugin, but otherwise was perfect.

Comment: And just a side note, I found a great REGEX tester here: https://regex101.com/ which let me figure out what exactly `^dog/([^/]+)/?$` was doing. The only caveat with this tester is you have escape the slashes like this: `^dog\/([^\/]+)\/?$`

Comment: @jsherk - only use `flush_rewrite_rules` when your plugin is activated, don't flush on every request! read [the usage note in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) for more info.

Comment: @Milo I just was reading that before I saw your comment, and was coming back to post exactly what you said. Thanks.

Comment: Some good related info in this other thread: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228538/does-flush-rewrite-rules-remove-all-rules-added-by-other-plugins-as-well-as-mi