# Does flush_rewrite_rules() remove all rules added by other plugins as well as mine?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am developing a plugin, and am using add_rewrite_rule followed by flush_rewrite_rules during plugin activation.

On plugin deactivation I am using just flush_rewrite_rules to remove the rule that I had added.

Now let's assume another plugin had also added a rewrite rule. Would calling flush_rewrite_rules not remove this other plugins rewrite rule as well, even though the other plugin is still active?

EDIT:

Some notes to remember:

- `flush_rules()` does the same as `flush_rewrite_rules()`. See Milo's comments below his accepted answer.
- There is an issue in bug tracker https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29118 that shows the best practice, but also shows the problem of having to use INIT to conitinually add your rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why you need to add rewrite rules on the `init` action on every request, as well as on plugin activation.

When your plugin deactivation hook is run, other plugin `init` hooks have already run, so their rules exist in the global variable that stores them for the life of each request.

Flushing rewrite rules empties the option that stores the rules long-term, and then repopulates it with whatever is in that global variable.

Comment: Just don't flush the rules on init too - will increase load much more than is needed!

Comment: The WordPress Codex specifically recommends that you do NOT run flush_rewrite_rules on `init` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: @jsherk You don't flush rules on `init`, but you must *add* them on `init` on every request, as well as any code that generates rules, like registering post types and taxonomies.

Comment: @Milo Okay now I see what you are saying. This makes more sense.

Comment: Another thought/question ... how does flush_rules() compare to flush_rewrite_rules()? When/why would you use one versus the other?

Comment: @jsherk they do the same thing, `flush_rules` is a method of the rewrite class, `flush_rewrite_rules` is a convenience function that just calls that class method on the global `$wp_rewrite` object.

Comment: @Milo Okay thanks for clarifying that they are the same. Just as a side note, it seems to me that there should be a way to remove a rewrite rule without having to call `flush_rewrite_rules()`. And there should be a way to add a rewrite rule without removing other custom rewrite rules that were added. Anyways I will post these suggestions in bug reporter.

Comment: Somebody already thought of it: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29118